# Yii использование ajax + jquery

Tags: jquery, framework, ajax, yii

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал работать с yii framework столкнулся с проблемой использования ajax и jquery. На просторах иннета нашел некую реализацию ajax запросов с использованием jquery:

```
<?=CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Принять', $this->createUrl('register/update/'),
array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){
        $(".operation")
        .text("bla-bla-bla")
        .fadeTo(0, 1);
    }',
    'data' => array('Register' => array(
        'id' => 'js:$(this).parent().parent().find("input.id").val()',
        'name' => 'js:$(this).parent().parent().find("input#name").val()',
        'surname' => 'js:$(this).parent().parent().find("input#surname").val()',
    )),
    'success' => 'function (data){
        $(".operation")
            .html(data)
            .fadeTo(0, 1)
            .fadeTo(2000, 0);
        return false;
    }',
),
array(
    'class' => 'submit',
)
);?>
```

Данный код работает, но никак не пойму как использовать здесь переменные. Т.е. я хочу чтобы после выполнения запроса я смог обратиться к элементу через $(this).parent()... отшагивая от текущей нажатой кнопки, после чего поместить ее в переменную и проводить с ней дальнейшие операции.
Запись типо`'complate' => 'js:var val = js:$(this).parent()...',` выдает ошибку, а вот такой код ошибки не выдает:`'complate' => 'js:alert("bla-bla-bla")',` (данный код помещаю после 'beforeSend')
Если кто знает как правильно использовать здесь переменные подскажите плиз.
И еще вопросик - стоит ли вообще применять такой способ ajax обработки в yii или стоит использовать стандартный метод, т.е. в js файле обрабатывать нажатие этой кнопки?

Comment: Такие ситуации Я называю борьбой с фреймворком. РНР ради РНР, или РНР ради js. Не знаю.

В любом случае,  Я бы не стал так делать. Лучше просто сделать обычную кнопку, или сабмит, при загрущке DOM навешать на него обработчик нажатия мыши, и играться в свое удовольствие.

Answer (score 1):

'complate' => new CJavaScriptExpression(" ВАШ КОД"); // то? не то?